# alignment when referring to structs vs variables

Tags: c++, memory

when we're talking about alignment we're always referring to variables inside a struct and not to single variables.

could you please tell me why is that?
when we're referring to a variable , would it take the whole size of "word"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because if you're messing with variable alignement you are either in the world of low level optimisation (based on cache line estimations and whatnot) or doing some embed programming.

Most developers don't do that and the ones who do are more likely to go read their plateforme specs and rethink about the alignement principles that they probably already know rather than discuss it on internet (there are exceptions of course, it's just not the general tendency).

I have yet to see a variable alignement which is not a derivate of:

```
// the array "cacheline" will be aligned to 128-byte boundary
alignas(128) char cacheline[128];
```

---

On the other hand you don't need very specific situations to see the impact of aggregate(struct) alignement on a program.

This is something a beginner will write and question at some point or another:

```
#include <iostream>

struct no_align
{
  char c;
  double d;
  int i;
};

struct align
{
  double d;
  int i;
  char c;
};

int     main(void)
{
  no_align      no_align_array[100];
  align         align_array[100];

  std::cout << sizeof(no_align_array) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(align_array) << std::endl;
}
```

On my machine the result is:

```
2400 
1600
```

And that's the point where you'll go around on internet asking why in the world one version makes you use `800` more bytes than the other if no teacher ever explained that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Every type has a size, which is fixed, and an alignment requirement.

A struct has members with their own alignment requirements. As a logical consequence, a struct must have an alignment requirement at least as strong as those of all its members. A struct may have to add padding so that all its members meet their alignment requirements.

An array stores multiple array elements consecutively without any padding. As a logical consequence, the size of any type must be a multiple of its alignment requirement (so a struct containing an int and a char cannot have an alignment requirement of four bytes and a size of five bytes, because that wouldn't work for the second array element in an array of two such structs).

Variables need to have addresses so their alignment requirements are satisfied, so your first sentence is wrong.

However, there is the "as-if" rule: Normally, the compiler has to do what the language tells it. But the "as-if" rule says that the compiler can do whatever it wants to do as long as a program cannot find the difference. So if storing an int on an unaligned address makes no difference (except maybe a tiny cost in time), the compiler is allowed to do this.